# disabling/enabling the form values in php based on the if condition on the same page

Tags: php, javascript

here what i want to do is based on the if condition's value the total form should be disabled, how can i do that, here is the code i tried....

```
if ($today1 >= $saturday && $today1 <= $season1)
    {
     document.getElementById('season').disabled = false;
    }
    else if($today1 >= $startdate_offseasona1 && $today1 <= $enddate_offseasona1 )
    {
    document.getElementById('season').disabled = true;
    }
    else if($today1 >= $startdate_seasona2 && $today1 <= $season2)
    {
    document.getElementById(seasons).disabled = false;
    }
```

and my form goes as follows:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="season" name="season">
Min_Custom_League_size<input type="text" name="min_custom_league_size" size="40"/><br/>
Max_Custom_League_size:<input type="text" name="max_custom_league_size" size="40"/><br/>
Ranked_League_size:<input type="text" name="ranked_league_size" size="40"/><br/>
Screen_Capacity:<input type="text" name="screen_capacity" size="40"/><br/>
Wide_Release_Screens:<input type="text" name="wide_release_screens" size="40"/><br/>
Limited_Release_Screens:<input type="text" name="limited_release_screens" size="40"/><br/>
Starting_Auction_Budget:<input type="text" name="starting_auction_budget" size="40"/><br/>
Weekly_Auction_Allowance:<input type="text" name="weekly_auction_allowance" size="40"/><br/>
Minimum_Auction_Bid:<input type="text" name="minimum_auction_bid" size="40"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

how can i do this based on the if condition value...what's wrong with my code??

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing PHP (server-side) with JavaScript (client-side), and you can't do that. In any case, you have to disable the `<input>` elements, not the form itself.

Here is how to do that with PHP only:

```
<?php
$disableForm = $today1 >= $startdate_offseasona1 && $today1 <= $enddate_offseasona1;
?>
<form action="" method="POST" id="season" name="season">
    Min_Custom_League_size<input type="text" <?php if($disableForm) echo 'disabled="disabled"'?> name="min_custom_league_size" size="40"/><br/>
<!-- repeat for all input elements -->
</form>
```

And here is a pure JavaScript way to disable the inputs unconditionally:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var frm = document.getElementById('season');
    var inputs = frm.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Note: you also have a typo inside your last `else if` block, it should be `disabled`, not `diabled`.

Comment: Read the question once again. The guy clearly confused b/w server-side and client-side scripting.

Comment: I tried like this got an error message as "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR in C:\xampp\htdocs\datefin.php on line 93" ie., the error is in the if condition..

Comment: @abc123, see my updated answer. I hadn't notice you were mixing PHP and JS.

Comment: @abc123, you **are** mixing languages, `document.getElementById` *is* JavaScript!

Comment: ohhhhh...thnks fr clarifying that to me....then hw can i do to disable or enable the form fields inside the if conditional block...

Comment: Did you try the PHP solution I suggested above?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11461/discussion-between-abc123-and-bfavaretto)

Answer (score 0):

Use this for disable all elements in the form. likewise you can enable form elements

```
var theform = document.getElementById('seasons');
for (i = 0; i < theform.length; i++) {
var formElement = theform.elements[i];
if (true) {
formElement.disabled = true;
}
}
```

Comment: i want to disable or enable the form fields when only the if condition failed so tell me solution to write code fr disabling/enabling the form inside the if conditional block..